# How make 'add members' functionality Django

Tags: python, django

I am doing a management tool web application. I would like user can click 'add members' button, and the member will be added under 'Members'. I am using ajax to retrieve data from database, but I do not know how to display 'username'. It only displays 'id'. Moreover, I would like added members to stay in page whenever user refreshes the page.

project_index.html

```
 <form action="" method="GET" id="selection-form">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                    <select id="member_list">
                            {% for user in user %}
                        <option value="{{user.pk }} }}">
                            {{ user.username }}
                        </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                     <input type="button" value="Add member" id="selection-button">
                     </form>
                    <div id="res"> </div>
```

views.py

```
def member_select(request):
    selection = request.GET.get('id',None)
    if selection:
        data = serializers.serialize('json',User.objects.filter(pk=selection))
    else:
        data = {}
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

base.html

```
  <script>
      var url = $( '#selection-button' ).attr( 'action' );
         $("#selection-button").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var value =$('#member_list').val();
     console.info('test',value)
      $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         url:'.',
         data:{
             id:value,
         },
         success:function (result) {
            $("#res").append(value);
           console.info(result)

         },
         error:function (result) {
              alert('error');

         }
       });
     });

  </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can write a serializer, and specify fields you want to display:

```
class UserSerializer:
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'username')
```

Comment: How to use this UserSerializer ? @Mohammad Ali

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserSerializer:
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'username')
    def create(self,validated_data):
        return User(**validated_data)
```

For view

```
class UserCreateAPIView(generic.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=UserSerializer
```

And I hope you was familiar with django rest

Comment: I have not get to rest framework part yet. Can I know what is the first part code for?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 concerns about how you are doing this:

#### First is that in your javascript you're reading the data wrong.

I inspected the result return from `django.core.serializers.serialize` the result only have those keys `['model', 'pk', 'fields']`.

this is why you can access `pk` attribute in your javascript but not `username` that is because `username` attribute is part of `fields` object.

so you should read `username` as `user.fields.username` not `user.username`

#### Second concern is that your version is not retrieving all fields by default:

Try to user `fields` keyword argument:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

> If you only want a subset of fields to be serialized, you can specify a fields argument to the serializer:

```
from django.core import serializers
...
data = serializers.serialize('xml', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
```

> In this example, only the name and size attributes of each model will be serialized. The primary key is always serialized as the pk element in the resulting output; it never appears in the fields part.

So in your case this should be something like

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', User.objects.filter(pk=selection), fields=('username','id'))
```

**I recommend that you use `django-rest-framework` just as @mohammad-ali described.**

`djanog-rest-framework` allows you to do more.